# Dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 14.04: We couldn’t update system reserved partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, boot-repair

My Windows boot is attempting to update itself (Feature update to Windows 10, version 1803), yet I am seeing the error `"We couldn’t update system reserved partition"`

Looking into this led me to the [following article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3086249/we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows) on the Microsoft Support site, the essence of which is `The System Reserved Partition (SRP) may be full` followed by `If you're updating Windows 10, you need to free up 13MB`

A layout of the SRP (the result of `dir /s`) can be found on https://pastebin.com/Gg32b9G5

Following the instructions for Windows 10 with GPT partition didn't resolve the issue. My working assumption is that either the `EFI\ubuntu` or the `boot-repair` directory in the SRP is taking up space the Microsoft isn't expecting to be taken up.

1. Can the `boot-repair` partition, which is taking up 62,085,307 bytes, be safely removed - perhaps partially? It appears to primarily contain two large (log?) files (see lines #595 and #607 in the link)
2. If I can't remove from `boot-repair`, are there files that can safely be removed from `EFI\ubuntu` (lines #558 to #575)
3. Is there a solution better than the two above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can remove boot-repair from your SRP. It plays no part in the boot-up process. I'd do so from Windows if you know how to access the SRP.

I would not delete the Ubuntu folder from SRP if I were you.